# Scylladb as Loki backend DB

Tags: logging, scylla, grafana-loki

Is it possible to use ScyllaDB as backend database for Loki storage system. As per the Loki documentation it supports Apache Cassandra. But there is nothing about ScyllaDB. Does anyone know about the ScyllaDB support in Loki.

Comment: Since I haven't tried this combination myself, I don't want to write an official "answer", but I just wanted to comment that ScyllaDB is designed to be drop-in compatible with Cassandra, so ideally (minus bugs) every application that works with Cassandra should work with ScyllaDB as well.

Comment: @Nadav Har'El Thanks for your input. That is what I am thinking too. I will try this and see.